# SWF playing error in Adobe Captivate

Tags: flash, adobe

I've created moving balls in Adobe Animate CC 2017 and then exported into SWF file. The animation is based on Action Script 3.0. I've a problem when importing the file in Adobe Captivate as the file won't play. The file in the following link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0znl5joiwduxh1a/balls2.swf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Captivate so can you confirm that normally it will run any AS3 code within a SWF?

Does this other file work correctly (balls will bounce)? Right-click to save: [**`SWF file`**](http://swf.wonderfl.net/swf/usercode/d/de/de5b/de5bce1c42bf6875fdb776d56c081ba9a6cb35b2.swf).

- If `YES` then the problem is in your own SWF's code.
- If `NO` then maybe Captivate doesn't parse the code part of any SWF (ie: it's only treated as some image or animation format). Possible also is the code parsing accepts simpler commands only, so check the manual for any AS3 code limitations mentioned.